# Is a Ribonuclease Inhibitor protein the only mechanism employed by the human cell to protect cellular RNA from degradation by endoribonuclease?

Tags: molecular-biology, cell-biology, molecular-genetics

Are there any other methods of protection for cellular RNA from degradation by endonuclease (specifically the Pancreatic Ribonuclease RNase II (Eosinophil-derived neurotoxin) and RNase III (Eosinophil cationic protein)) besides Ribonuclease Inhibitor Proteins? Perhaps a method that interacts with the RNA itself rather than compromising the RNase?

Would 5' end capping or 3' end polyadenylation which are normally used to protect from exoribonuclease also protect from endoribonuclease? Could a Ribonucleoprotein Particle (RNP) type strategy protect from degradation?

Thank you,

CDB

Comment: Endoribonuclease is not that high in the cytoplasm AFAIK. Yes binding with proteins does confer some protection. Secondary structures can also offer protection from certain RNAses, but not others.